# QEMU PCI Device fires forever

Tags: interrupt, qemu, pci

I've written a small PCI device in QEMU using https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/v2.7.0/hw/misc/edu.c as a base, and https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/6788a577c394a2fc512d8f3df0806d84dc09f355/kernel_module/pci.c to interact with it. However, interrupts appear to fire roughly ever 2 seconds.

I write data to the PCI device to acknowledge the interrupt, and I can see that before and after the call to:

```c
    if (!device->irq_status && !device_msi_enabled(device)) {
        printf("Set state from %d ", device->pdev.irq_state);
        pci_set_irq(&device->pdev, 0);
        printf("to %d\n", device->pdev.irq_state);
    }
```

The output is

```
Set state from 0 to 0
Set state from 0 to 0
Set state from 0 to 0
Set state from 0 to 0
```

I can't tell what could cause the interrupt to continue firing - is there a property I've forgotten?